# D-efficiency value does not vary in D-optimal design of experiment

Tags: r, experiment-design

I am designing an experiment using D-Optimal design. With full factorial design I have to do 200 runs. With D-optimal, I can choose the number of runs I want to do and I evaluate the design using D-efficiency value.

My question is the D-efficiency value varies in order of 0.001 when I change the number of runs. Can anyone give me an indication why this is happening? I expected larger number when I chose to run many experiment.

Comment: Are you asking why your results only changed slightly when you switched from a full-factorial design to a d-optimal design with far fewer samples?

Comment: In the case that anyone is still interested in this Q, it would be helpful to know the model type, design space, and computational algorithm used for calculation of D-optimality and D-efficiency.